# How to shift a value one record 'down'

Tags: ms-access

Suppose we have a field ("Flag"). How we can shift records of this flag in another field ("ShiftField") by using SQL code?

See the example:

```
ID   Flag     ShiftFlag
1    0  
2    1        0
3    1        1
4    1        1
5    0        1
6    0        0
7    1        0
8    1        1
9    1        1
10   0        1
```

My efforts already was something like below:

```
for i=1 to n str = 
  "UPDATE HoboData Set ShiftFlag = Wet_Estimated80 WHERE ID = " & i + 1 
next i 
Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str, Connect)
```

but this way is very slow

Comment: my efforts already was something like below
for i=1 to n
str="UPDATE HoboData Set  ShiftFlag  = Wet_Estimated80  WHERE ID = " & i + 1
next i
Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str, Connect)
but this way is very slow

Comment: the database is in access but the programming is by Visual.net I just need the SQL syntax for this problem

Answer (score 2):

This will do the trick in recent versions of SQL Server and Oracle:

```
SELECT ID, Flag,
  LAG(Flag) OVER(ORDER BY id) AS ShiftFlag
FROM tab
ORDER BY id;
```

If you don't have LAG(), for example in MS SQL Server 2008, you can use ROW_NUMBER() like this:

```
;WITH num AS (
  SELECT ID, Flag, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY id) AS n FROM tab
)
SELECT t1.ID, t1.Flag, t2.Flag AS ShiftFlag
FROM num t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN num t2 ON t2.n = t1.n - 1
ORDER BY t1.ID;
```

Tested on [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4c2c7a/10).

Comment: Well, if we assume that those `ID` have no gaps, your `ROW_NUMBER()` version can be made to fit.

Comment: @ypercube: unforunately SQLFiddle doesn't support Access.